# How to Move child to the same spot on a new parent

Tags: transforms, parent, linked-data

So I have an child parented to an object. I'd like to move it to the same location on a new parent (which will often be a linked duplicate). I've tried various combinations with keep transform, clear parent inverse and apply scale and can't find a way that works. Is this even possible? How can I achieve this? Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start by using these object constraints to your child:

[image]

then just animate the influences to the "opposite" values, so 1 to 0 and 0 to 1 like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this does what I need. I wasn't trying to animate it, but it let me put the child in the right place. I could then apply the constraint, change the parent (keeping the transform) and it ends up where I want it. I'm just surprised it seems so convoluted.

Comment: you are welcome